# what does n^O(1/ε) means?

Tags: algorithm, traveling-salesman, approximation

I often find n^O(1/ε) in approximation algorithms. for example, in euclidean tsp, the number of portals(with its possible state) is equal to n^O(1/ε).

[image: source]

here is the link to the source
http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/schultes/lebenslauf/publications/euclTSPsummary.pdf

can someone explain why 3^4m = n^O(1/ε)?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the complexity of approximation algorithms depends on the precision wanted, often noted by ε to say you want the ratio of your answer to the best one to differ by no more than ε.

Here, this means that the dependence is in the exponent of the time complexity, as the algorithm is polynomial for every ε but with a bigger exponent the smaller ε is. Namely, here the exponent of the time complexity as a function of ε grows as a O(1/ε).

Indeed, in this paper it is said that "*The parameter* m *must lie in the interval [k/ε, 2k/ε]*" and 4^k=O(n^4), so 3^(4m) = 3^(O(k/ε)) = 3^(O(log(n)/ε)) = n^(O(1/ε)).